# Pandas: Explode list of dictionary of a specific row into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As title suggest,
I am stuck in a situation where I need to explode one row of a dataframe into multiple rows.

Current state of dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
op_d = {'A': [['NULL', 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL']],
        'V':[[{'2016': '488.386000'},{'2017': '469.508000'},
              {'2018': '445.510000'},{'2019': '579.299000'},
              {'2020': '493.786000'}]],
        'Q':[[{'2016': '488.386000'},{'2017': '469.508000'},
              {'2018': '445.510000'},{'2019': '579.299000'},
               {'2020': '493.786000'}]],
         'Z': [['NULL', 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(op_d)
```

[image: df]

desired state of dataframe:

```
op_d2 = {'Date':[2016,2017,2018,2019,2020],'A': ['NULL', 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL'],
        'V':[488.386000,469.508000,445.510000,579.299000,493.786000],
        'Q':[488.386000,469.508000,445.510000,579.299000,493.786000],
        'Z': ['NULL', 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL']}
result_df = pd.DataFrame(op_d2)
result_df
```

[image: result_df]

What I did was, took key of dictionary into a separate column 'Date' and kept the values of columns as it  is. Where ever it is NULL, it will remain as it is.

All the columns will have similar dictionary. i.e. same date ranges.

I'm receiving original response in json format, converting it to dataframe to perform some calculation. I'd appreciate any help.

Original json response:

```
  { 'Prop1': '',
   'Prop2': ['Somedata', 'SomeData2'],
   'Prop3': 5,
   'Prop4': '',
   'StartDate': '',
   'Function': 'ABC',
   'Identifier': 'ID001',
   'Col2': 2,
   'Prop5': 'XYZ',
   'Frequency': '',
   'Limit': '',
   'Rows': [{'Row': ['136.731000', '2016']},
            {'Row': ['135.331000', '2017']},
            {'Row': ['163.965000', '2018']},
            {'Row': ['153.371000', '2019']},
            {'Row': ['161.864000', '2020']}]},

}
```

Comment: I think pandas allows you to read straight from JSON formats. Why not `df = pd.read_json(file_name, orient='columns')`? See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html).

Comment: I already did that. then cleaned data, made some transformation, and reached to 'current state'.

Comment: If you've already loaded the json, then can you clarify what problem you are having? You loaded the json and then converted that to a dictionary, and then you want to know how to convert that dictionary to another dataframe? What does the original json look like? I'm assuming pandas is not loading that properly?

Comment: I have added original json response. however that is not relevant here. I have hundreds of identifier. some of them I just need to pass on as it is which is fine. 
Issue is I have to perform calculation between identifiers by year ('Row'). i.e. ID003 + ID005 for each of 2016,2017,2018,2019 and 2020. so that's where I'm stuck .

Comment: in my example, A, V , Q and Z are just another identifiers and 'Current State of Dataframe' is generated using Identifiers and Rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't make any claims about efficiency, perhaps this does what you need.

```
op_d_new = {k:(v[0] if v[0][0]=='NULL' else \
               [list(j.values())[0] for j in v[0]]) for k,v in op_d.items()}
for v in op_d.values():
    if v[0][0] == 'NULL':
        continue
    dates = [list(j.keys())[0] for j in v[0]]
    break
op_d_new.update({'Dates':dates})

df = pd.DataFrame(op_d_new)
df
```

```
      A           V           Q     Z Dates
0  NULL  488.386000  488.386000  NULL  2016
1  NULL  469.508000  469.508000  NULL  2017
2  NULL  445.510000  445.510000  NULL  2018
3  NULL  579.299000  579.299000  NULL  2019
4  NULL  493.786000  493.786000  NULL  2020
```